# IOS swift app crash tapping in textfields (NSNull length - unrecognized selector to instance)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, selector

Swift app crashes when typing on every textfield

Everything goes unless a textfield get tapped. 
When I tap textfields in the same view all it's ok but when I change view and so have another controller and tap in any textfield app crash.

Stack trace:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance

Comment: What's the code that causes the crash ?

Comment: can you show some code related to your textfield tap action

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `UITextField` has some value (maybe `textField.text`) that has not the correct type. The `length` method is often used on `NSString` and causes crashed when used on some others types that do not implement it (e.g. `NSNumber`).
I advise you to double check your `UITextField` to see if all your values are those that are meant to be.

EDIT : I just re-read your post. It looks like you are passing nil or an NSNull object to `textField.text` (maybe in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` which causes the crash. Change this to pass a String and it should fix it.

Comment: EDIT : I just  remove tabBarController and NavigationController from storyboard and create it again and this just fix the problem...can't figure why it happened and why this resolve the proble